# GNOME desktop : assign double key-presses as a shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-shell

Is there any way to assign double key-press to a shortcut, e.g. double-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-press to switch language source?

Comment: I have changed "clicks" to "key-presses" as "click" is usually associated to mouse-button press whereas it seems you want to press keyboard keys twice. If it is not what you intended, please feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: @pomsky your edits are very useful